# how to diagnose a problem in git commit history

Tags: git

I have a project in swift and I use git flow. I found a bug in my project, but I don't know when and where it was introduced in my commit history. how can I find the bug in my commit history? Is there any tools to search in commits?

Comment: Try `git bisect` ?

Comment: Bisect/Binary search. But you'd have to "tried" each time to see if the bug is present... Or if you know where it is (know the modification/file), XCode and its git diff/time travel can show you the commit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272090/where-is-the-xcode-side-by-side-code-comparison-option/69272179#69272179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code on your terminal:

```
git bisect start
```

this will show you the broken version branch and info for debugging
there is a good doc for this job
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect